# Getting JavaScript oninput function to change background color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have some code that works for a password form where the user is filling out their details and then 2 of the boxes only work or become typable if they enter a number/age greater than that specified. i now want to take it one step further and make it obvious to the user that those boxes are only editable certain times by colouring them in a different colour. for some reason though the new code within the JS is not working.
code is below:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron" id="firstform">
    <h1>Sign up page</h1> 
    <form id="myform">

        <label>Username </label> <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Username must be unique" class="mytooltip"><br>

        <div class="pwordCheck">
            <label>Password </label> <input type="password" id="pword" data-placement="bottom" title="" onkeyup="passwordValidation(); return false;" data-original-title="Password must be more than 6 characters long" class="mytooltip"><br>
            <label>Confirm Password </label>  <input type="password" id="confpword"  onkeyup="passwordValidation(); return false;" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Passwords must match" class="mytooltip">
            <span id="themessage" class="themessage"></span><br> 
        </div>

        <label>Email </label> <input type="email" id="e-mail"><br>

        <label>Age </label> <input type="number" id="age" oninput="ifOfAge(); return false;"><br>

        <label>Can you drive? </label> <input type="text" id="drive" disabled><br>

        <label>What is your occupation? </label> <input type="text" id="occupation" disabled><br>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="usernameAlreadyExists(); return false;">
    </form>  

  </div>



</div>
```

css:

```
input#drive{
    background-color: #999;
}

input#occupation{
    background-color: #999;
}
```

js:

```
function ifOfAge() {

  var age = document.getElementById("age");
  var drive = document.getElementById("drive");
  var occupation = document.getElementById("occupation");
  var white = "#fff";

  if (age.value >= 21) {
    drive.disabled = false;
    occupation.disabled = false;
  } else if (age.value >= 16) {
    drive.disabled = false;
    occupation.style.backgroundColor = white;
  } else {
    drive.disabled = true;
    occupation.disabled = true;
    drive.style.backgroundColor = white;
    occupation.style.backgroundColor = white;
  }


}
```

Comment: It is working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/1r61574p/

Comment: What exactly is not working here? are you runing the script inside `document ready` or including it at the end of the document?

Comment: @nevermind have you changed anything?

Comment: @AntonioSmoljan the problem is that when you start typing it turns the background colour to not the one i require it to. moreso, when i start deleting characters, aka oninput it remains the colour it just changed to instead of turning back again

Comment: @ObeseOctopus, no, as you can see, just didn't used your white var... However, that doesn't change anything, here is white var used: http://jsfiddle.net/1r61574p/2/

Answer (score 0):

Color must be enclosed within quotes. Like below. Wherever you have used white surround it with quotes

```
 drive.style.backgroundColor = "white";
```

Comment: i put white as variable at the top

Comment: Better jquery validation wiil be the best

Comment: @ObeseOctopus Sorry I missed that..  Are you getting any script  errors in console?

Answer (score 0):

you can make change color for disabled input like this.

**EDIT**

```
function ifOfAge() {

  var age = document.getElementById("age");
  var drive = document.getElementById("drive");
  var occupation = document.getElementById("occupation");
  var white = "#fff";

  if (age.value >= 21) {
    drive.disabled = false;
    occupation.disabled = false;
  } else if (age.value >= 16) {
    drive.disabled = false;
    occupation.style.backgroundColor = white;
  } else {
    drive.disabled = true;
    occupation.disabled = true;
    drive.style.backgroundColor = "#999";
    occupation.style.backgroundColor = "#999";
  }
}
```

You can make it more nice if you used jQuery and plugin jQuery Validation or even more nice with this [one](http://jplugins.directory/jquery-validate-bootstrap-popover/?show=demo).

Comment: i cant get on the link as it is blocked but your original solution is no different to mine except the colour is different at the bottom

Comment: How about this [link](http://mingliangfeng.me/github%20project/2013/08/08/jquery-validate-bootstrap-popover-demo/)?